# How the function calls works in terms of Stack and Code memory?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, stack, embedded, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been trying to understand how memory works, what happens step by step inside execution of the application in terms of memory, specially in embedded system. More of context in C/C++

- Out of Stack, heap, static and Code memory of a application, which is Stored in RAM or volatile memory and which part is stored in non-volatile memory? Or when a application is executed, the whole application is copied to RAM or volatile memory?
- When a function is called, does all the assembly instruction of that function gets copied to the stack or only memory is allocated to function?
- If only memory is allocated to the function in real time, that means the address of those variable has to be added to the assembly code of the function, how does that happen?
- Who does all this in an embedded system stack memory allocation etc in a embedded system when we write code for it in C? There is no OS in the MCU to do memory management for us so who manages this memory allocation during function calls in MCU

Comment: There is no C/C++. C or C++.

Comment: All of your ideas are used. Everything depends of hardware and ABI. Even newers uPs virtualize memory do your code can be on the disk and can be loaded when needed to the RAM :)

Comment: See [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102) or the more general [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277536)

Answer (score 3):

> - Out of Stack, heap, static and Code memory of a application, which is
>   Stored in RAM or volatile memory and which part is stored in
>   non-volatile memory? Or when a application is executed, the whole
>   application is copied to RAM or volatile memory?
> - When a function is called, does all the assembly instruction of that
>   function gets copied to the stack or only memory is allocated to
>   function?
> - If only memory is allocated to the function in real time, that means
>   the address of those variable has to be added to the assembly code of
>   the function, how does that happen?

For a comprehensive and correct understanding of code execution in bare-metal (without OS,  and OS environments (embedded systems), different memory structures and all their internals, I would recommend you to cover this book - [Extreme C (Auth: Kamran Amini)](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/extreme-c/9781789343625/), especially these sections:

1. Chapter 2: From Source to Binary
2. Chapter 4: Process Memory Structure
3. Chapter 5: Stack and Heap

In my experience, heresay and random comments will hurt your understanding instead and you will be barely able to make sense out of it. Consult authentic published content.

Answer (score 1):

> in embedded system

I am answering assuming a system without [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), assuming some small microcontroller. Overall, note the that answers highly depend on specific configuration of specific system. In the end, you can store everything in volatile memory if you want, and you can configure microcontrollers that way.

> Out of Stack, heap, static and Code memory of a application, which is Stored in RAM or volatile memory and which part is stored in non-volatile memory?

There are sections, see like https://www.embeddedtutor.com/2019/07/memory-layout-executable-in-embedded.html .  TBH it's really trivial - if something changes, it's volatile, if something does not change and persist between power losses, it's non-volatile. Let's say:

| what | where |
| --- | --- |
| stack | volatile |
| heap | volatile |
| static | initialization of static variables is stored in non-volatile memory, static variables themselves are stored in volatile memory. I.e. [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) |
| Code | We live on [Harvard architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) and assembly instructions do not change, so they go to non-volatile memory |

> Or when a application is executed, the whole application is copied to RAM or volatile memory?

No, it is not copied.

But, anyway, you can configure a microcontroller to execute instructions from volatile memory, like [STM32 code_in_ram](https://dev.to/rajeevbharol/executing-code-from-ram-on-stm32-arm-microcontrollers-2k2l). Still there is no copy (there can be, you can write code for that...), the instructions are there. I.e. it all depends on specific configuration.

> If only memory is allocated to the function in real time, that means the address of those variable has to be added to the assembly code of the function, how does that happen?

There is a [stack pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_register) that contains the location of the top of the stack. It is incremented or decremented depending on if adding or removing data from the stack (and note, that for example on x86 stack grows towards *decreasing* memory addresses, like upside down). The functions themselves manage the stack, whereas functions are created by a C compiler and the C compiler creates that code to manage that stack.

There are standards that specify how it specifically works on specific architectures - these standard specify architecture [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). For example, [x86-64 ABI](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) or [ARM ABI](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa). They specify what registers are used, how stack is used and passed, etc. Then compilers "implement that ABI" - create assembly code that adheres to the rules given in ABI standards.

> Who does all this in an embedded system stack memory allocation etc in a embedded system when we write code for it in C?

C code itself manages memory by itself. Compiler glues it together.

> so who manages this memory allocation during function calls in MCU

The code itself, I guess? (Nowadays) C standard libraries are written in C, and some are open source. Newlib is a popular free C standard library implementation for embedded systems - you can inspect [it's malloc implementation](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/mallocr.c).

Answer (score 0):

> Who does all this in an embedded system stack memory allocation etc in a embedded system when we write code for it in C? There is no OS in the MCU to do memory management for us so who manages this memory allocation during function calls in MCU

The programmer's interface in C is the main.c file:

```
int main (){

// User code here

return 0;
}
```

But technically, your IDE (Keil uVision or Code Composer Studio etc.) along with it's RTE (Run-time environment) component, places a boilperlate code of initialization and de-initialization files (commonly known as MCU startup code) before and after this main.c file, during building (compilation) phase of your source code for that particular target hardware such as Tiva C TM4C123GH6PM or STM32F400 etc.

The code inside these startup/initialization files initializes your stack and heap memory, clock-gating controls of your mcu, setups up different peripherals (gpio, serial, i2c etc.), interrupt vector table, PC (program counter), SP (stack pointer) etc. and a lot more other things.

You can open a debug session of a simple program for your target MCU, while configuring it to 'stop at first assembly instruction/startup' and then performing stepping operations to go through all the code until you reach main.c file.

The findings are fantastic.